# Rspec hangs after it finishes running through my tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Has anyone seen this problem before? Sometimes when running specs for my Rails 3.2.14 project rspec seems to finish as usual:

```
Finished in 1.27 seconds
6 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/my_spec.rb:123 # Hello world 1
rspec ./spec/models/my_spec.rb:234 # Hello world 2
```

but then it just hangs there and won't let me continue working in that shell. I can kill -9 the process from another terminal tab, or just start a new shell and run the tests again there, but it makes test driven development a huge pain.

When I restart my computer, the problem goes away for a while, but it always happens again eventually. After it hangs once, it keeps hanging every time I run rspec, even if I run different tests in a different project. The same tests in the same projects pass just fine on my coworkers' computers every time.

I'm not sure what information would help to answer this question so let me know if there is something I should add to this post. I'm running ruby 2.0.0p195 and rails 3.2.14. I've got Mac OS 10.7.5. I use zsh and rbenv.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: This might not be helpful, but sometimes is. Next time it happens. Figure out the pid for the process and try running lsof -p <pid>. Maybe you will see a file or a port open or something it's hanging onto for some reason.

Comment: Thanks rainkinz, good to know, that helped identify the source of the problem!

Comment: Awesome. It's amazing how handly lsof is. So in your answer you say SimpleCov was the issue. What was the output of lsof that helped you identify that as the issue if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: ruby    3963 lucasbraun    9r   REG               14,4      4369 12113562 /Users/lucas/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/simplecov-html-0.7.1/public/smoothness/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out with a friend's help. All it took was removing SimpleCov from my spec_helper. Not sure why SimpleCov was causing the issue, but I'll post an update here if I find out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding the following to my spec_helper.rb:

```
SimpleCov.start do
  use_merging false
end
```

Note that I'm running on a virtual box vm with a synched directory.

Here's the explanation I found as to why this works:

"When simplecov exists, by default it will try to merge the recorded coverage with what's on disk. To avoid corruption it uses a lock file to guard this merge. Because my virtual box shared fs is not actually posix compliant, the lock file would never acquire, and silently block forever here.

Since I don't care about merging coverage results, the solution for me was to simply disable this behavior with the use_merging flag."

https://gist.github.com/k-yamada/3930916